# Undefined reference to QMediaPlayer

Tags: c++, qt, media

I'm trying to write a small video player using Qt. So, i've read tutorial and wrote some code.

```
QVideoWidget *video = new QVideoWidget(&w);
QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer();
player->setVideoOutput(video);
player->setMedia(QUrl("Some url"));
player->play();
```

I've included headers also:

```
#include <QtMultimediaWidgets/QVideoWidget>
#include <QtMultimedia/QMediaPlayer>
```

But when i compile my program i see that:

```
undefined reference to `QVideoWidget::QVideoWidget(QWidget*)
undefined reference to `QMediaPlayer::setVideoOutput(QVideoWidget*)
undefined reference to `QMediaContent::QMediaContent(QUrl const&)
undefined reference to `QMediaPlayer::setMedia(QMediaContent const&, QIODevice*)
undefined reference to `QMediaContent::~QMediaContent()
undefined reference to `QMediaPlayer::play()
undefined reference to `QMediaContent::~QMediaContent()
```

I really can't understand what is the problem. Help me please. Qt 5.3, Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: You're getting a linker error - this is probably because you haven't linked to the Qt libraries.

Comment: God.. It was 'cause i didnt added `multimedia multimediawidgets` to my `.pro` file. Thanks!

Comment: @Efog can you mark your question as solved? Good luck with Qt!

Comment: i can answer my own question, but mark as solved only 2 days later. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.
You just need to add `multimedia multimediawidgets` to your `.pro` file in `QT` section.